# EntityFramework context across multiple projects or joining between two contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class library project containing an EF Core db context. This is part of a framework.

I want to extend this context but without making changes to the framework project. The second context would use the same database.

I created another db context in a different class library (something similar to [this](https://blog.tekspace.io/code-first-multiple-db-context-migration/)). This works ok, I can make queries and create migrations separately from the other context.

But for example if I have a User entity in the first context and UserBooks in the second, when I try to make a `join` between the two contexts it doesn't work, getting exception

*System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entityType*

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13775).

Also tried with latest NuGet package [3.0.0-preview3.19153.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/3.0.0-preview3.19153.1) but the only difference is that the error message is better

*Cannot use multiple DbContext instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance*

Is there any way to

a. make joins between two contexts

or

b. extend a context in a separate project without making any (or minimal) changes to the 'main' context

Answer (score 3):

Two db-contexts means two connections. You can't join through different connections.

#### 1. Load Data into Program

You can load you data to your program and join there. Be aware, that this is dangerous on big datasets.

```
var customers = new Ctx1().Customers.ToList(); // ToList() loads the data into your program
var orders = new Ctx2().Orders.ToList();

// Now we're not in the db anymore. We can do a simple List-Join:
customers.Join(orders, c => c.CustomerId, o => o.CustomerId, (c, o) => new { Customer = c, Order = o });
```

#### 2. Extend your existing Context

If you want to stick to one connection you could simply extend your Context. Be aware that you're in one transaction this way.

```
public class FrameworkContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedContext : FrameworkContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Now you're allowed to join:

```
var ctx = new ExtendedContext();

var myResult = ctx.customers.Join(ctx.orders, c => c.CustomerId, o => o.CustomerId, (c, o) => new { Customer = c, Order = o });
```

Comment: I know, but I would need to retrieve all data from db, then join on the 'client' side. I would like the join to be made on the db in a single query

Comment: This may be OK for small datasets, but it is definitely not the recommended approach.

Comment: If it is one Db and one connection can be used, the obious solution is to extend the context. Added the 2nd solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your second context inherit the first.

```
public class MyFirstContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class MySecondContext : MyFirstContext
{
    public DbSet<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, your second context could be in a different assembly. Now you only need `MySecondContext` in your application. You will be able to join `Users` and `UserBooks`.